# linq max lazy evaluation

Tags: c#, linq, lazy-evaluation

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how lazy evaluation relates to the linq Max operator.

This is my code:

```
        var someList = new List<someType>
        {
            new someType { decimalValue = 32 }
        };
```

`line1:     var valA = someList.Any() ? someList.Max(s => s.decimalValue) : 0.0M;`

`line2:     var valB = someList.Any() ? someList.Max(s => s.decimalValue) : 0.0M;`

`line3:     var valC = valB;`

When stepping through the code I see the following behaviour:

After line 1 has executed, `valA = 0, valB = 0, valC = 0`

After line 2 has executed, `valA = 32, valB = 0, valC = 0`

After line 3 has executed, `valA = 32, valB = 32, valC = 32`

Why does `valA` only show a value after `valB` is assigned, and why does `valB` only show a value once `valC` is assigned?

Below is a screenshot of my debugger.  I guess there must be something non-standard about my IDE.

[image: IDE image]
<sub>(source: [toastermagic.co.uk](http://toastermagic.co.uk/images/linqMax.png))</sub>

Comment: `Any` or `Max` are executed immediately.

Comment: @TimSchmelter *Both* of them execute immediately (although the other overload of `Any` is deferred).

Comment: @Servy: That's what i've said, apart from that the overload is deferred. [**It**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) is also executed immediately. It just uses a predicate in the `foreach` and returns true if any of the element returns true for it, otherwise false.

Comment: @TimSchmelter You said `Any` *or* `Max` as opposed to `Any` *and* `Max`.  It's not just one, it's both.

Comment: great, now that that's clear, could either of you explain the behaviour I'm seeing in my IDE?

Comment: BTW, a more LINQ-ish style would be `var val1 = anotherList.DefaultIfEmpty().Max();`.

Comment: @AllonGuralnek although the replacement for my original code would have to be `var val1 = someList.DefaultIfEmpty(new someType { decimalValue = 0 }).Max(s => s.decimalValue);` which is not quite so elegant :(

Comment: @Paul: Then you can do `someList.Select(s => s.decimalValue).DefaultIfEmpty().Max()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Max` operator executes immediately, it is not deferred at all.  What you're seeing is just the normal behavior of the debugger.  When it has a line highlighted it means, "I'm about to run this line" rather than, "I just ran this line".  You'll always need to be on the 'next' line to see the results of a given line of code.

It seems that you have accounted for this.  The fact that you are see all changes (this shouldn't be just LINQ specific) a line late probably means your source code and the executable are a bit out of sync.  You should do a clean and re-bulid of the solution and then everything should be fine.  I'm guessing that you made some small modification to the source code that didn't get picked up properly in a build and so the line numbers in the executable vs. the source code are each off by one.

If something is really, really wrong, you can try moving the code to a new project entirely (if your code base is small enough) in an attempt to get rid of whatever corrupted or broken file/setting is causing this problem.

Comment: I'm aware of how the IDE steps through code, see the diagram I added in the edit.

Comment: I did of think that, but cleaned then rebuilt solution and still the same

Comment: works fine in a new solution - I cannot explain this as I deleted the obj and bin folders to make sure it was re-compiling. oh well. thanks

Comment: Added comment to the answer, since it seems to have solved the problem.  It seems the problem really is something being out of sync between builds, given that a new project fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot Replicate:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = (from n in Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
                    select new { value = (decimal)n })
                   .ToList();

        var valA = data.Any() ? data.Max(s => s.value) : 0.0M;
        Console.WriteLine("A = {0}, B = {1}, C = {2}", valA, 0, 0);

        var valB = data.Any() ? data.Max(s => s.value) : 0.0M;
        Console.WriteLine("A = {0}, B = {1}, C = {2}", valA, valB, 0);

        var valC = valB;
        Console.WriteLine("A = {0}, B = {1}, C = {2}", valA, valB, valC);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Works as expected.

Looks to be a misread of the debugger.